# Translating a Borel measurable set to overlap another?

Tags: real-analysis

So this come up as a subproblem that once solve, will help me solve 2 of my homework problem.

Let $A$ and $B$ be 2 Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $0<m(A),m(B)<\infty$ ($m$ is the Lebesgue meausure). Prove that there exist an $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $m(A\bigcap B+r)>0$ (where $B+r$ is $B$ translated by $r$).

So far, I'm pretty much stuck on the general method. The problem can be reduced to a version where $A$ and $B$ are closed nowhere dense set. Also, the set of all possible $r$ must be open, so we could start by looking at only $r$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ or something.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the Lebesgue density theorem.

---

Seeing as the question is a month old, I'll add some details. By the Lebesgue density theorem, there is $\epsilon>0$ and points $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that 
$$m(A\cap (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon))>\epsilon, \quad m(B\cap (b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon))>\epsilon$$ 
Translate $B$ by $a-b$, thus bringing both intervals into one. There is too much of $A$ and $B+(a-b)$ in this interval for them to be disjoint.

Replacing "$>\epsilon$" with "$>\frac32\epsilon$", you can also get an open interval of values $r$ such that $A\cap (B+r)$ has positive measure (and with some lower bound on the measure of intersection).

Comment: Well I totally forgot about this one. It would have been useful for one of my more recent homework assignment too, though people also mentioned this theorem in my other question. Too bad I can't use it though, because we don't learn about them. But I accepted this answer since it does answer the question.